# How to hide or change appearance of the countdown for next queue item?

Tags: google-cast

I'm developing a CAF Cast Receiver and have question about queue functionality. The `cast-media-player` offers built-in functionality for displaying a view that let the users know that there another item coming up soon. The view is displayed 20 seconds from the end of the current item and has text "Your video will play in XX"

I'm looking for a way to at least localize this text, is that possible? The div that holds the text has id `nextMetadataCountdown` but I can't seem to access that from javascript.

if not, is it possible to hide this view so we can present a custom view?

Answer (score 1):

The text is hardcoded in the receiver framework.  You can prevent it from being displayed entirely by adding the following CSS:

```css
        cast-media-player {
            --next-preview-visibility: hidden;
        }
```